# NSScrollView content and scroller insets

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, appkit

What would be the best way to create content and scroller insets on an NSScrollView like one can set on a UIScrollView?

I'd like to be able to add a footer which is not spanned by the vertical scroller like that found at the bottom of Mail.app's sidebar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have an `NSView` that contains both your `NSScrollView` and your footer's view, with the scroll view's frame set to not overlap the footer.

Comment: Was hoping to avoid this altogether, but it seems to be the only way

Comment: Yeah. Plus it avoids any future peculiarities that could arise.